# Load Target iFrame on same page

Tags: html

I have a page where an iframe is loaded into the body content of the page. It works fine. However, I'm struggling to get the second link to replace the current frame and NOT go under the current frame. (it loads both) This is what I have:

```
  <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://test.com/test/show.html" target="myFrame_mi_g">Graph</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://test.com/test/show2.html" target="myFrame_mi_r&gp">Graph Two</a></li>
    </ul>
```

The iFrames

```
<iframe style="border:none; height: 100%; width: 100%;" name="myFrame_mi_g" id="link"></iframe>
<iframe style="border:none; height: 100%; width: 100%;" name="myFrame_mi_r&gp" id="link"></iframe>
```

Comment: i'm not sure if i understood you right. but i think you should change the `target` of the second `<a>` to **myFrame_mi_g**

Comment: Im stupid. Yes. Thanks